# Is there any way to use Hearthstone/BattleNet on an account under parental control

Tags: hearthstone, windows

I have a Windows PC with Hearthstone running fine on my Administrator account (Account A).
I would like to have it working in an account with Parental Controls (we'll call Account B), which in turn means that it can't be an Administrator account.

When I attempt to run from Account B, it displays [this error message](https://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/BLZBNTBGS8000002A).
I know that Blizzard says "Our games require admin access to run and update" but I was looking for a work-around.

Any solution would be appreciated.

PS. I'm a Linux guy, and not really proficient with Windows.

Comment: Ask for your parent to install it for you? This isn't really about game installation so much as it is bypassing account restrictions.

Comment: I have admin account there. And it is installed, however it does not work on non-admin account.

Comment: Okay. I'd clarify that in your question, then. It's not about installing it under parental controls, but using it. That, I think we might be able to help with.

Comment: Hopeffully it is is now clear.

Comment: Can you run the Hearthstone executable directly without Battle.net from a regular user account?

Comment: Well when I click on the hearthstone icon on the desktop this error appears (I can't check what the link points to as this computer is not in my home, and I don't have a gaming windows handy).

Comment: Doesn´t hearthstone need the Battle Net Desktop app to run to be started ? I would start the app with admin and let the "child" use it from there.

Answer (score 3):

According to a Battle.net thread I found on this same issue, Account B needs full read/write permissions for `C:\ProgramData\Blizzard Entertainment`

Alternatively, try running Battle.net "As Administrator" on Account B, this might require an admin password.

Solutions found in this thread: http://us.battle.net/en/forum/topic/11747004646